# Некорректное отображение строковых данных в SQL Managment Studio

Tags: mysql, sql, преобразование

В таблице есть данные с типом Binary, но я знаю, что закодированы там строки.
Я конвертирую эти данные в NVARCHAR, но на выходе получаю китайские иероглифы.
Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема?
Пример запроса:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),field) FROM Table tb
```

Comment: Известная проблема, нужно применить к результату какую-нибудь строковую функцию, например извлечь подстроку (на всю длину)

Comment: Покажите код, как данные попадают в БД. Как строка была записана в тип binary.

Comment: Management Studio - это среда для работы с Sql Server. Почему в метках стоит MySql - совершенно другая СУБД?

Comment: Попродуйте VARCHAR вместо NVARCHAR, возможно с коллацией поиграться. Ещё пришлите пример binary без конвертации

Comment: Если взять текст на кириллице в кодировке win1251, записать как бинарные данные, и попытаться прочитать как UTF-16 (NVARCHAR), то получим китайские иероглифы. Преобразуйте в однобайтовый VARCHAR

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поиграться с типами данных. Напишите для своего заприоса примерно следующие прообразования:

```
SELECT *,
  CAST(my_varchar AS VARCHAR(100)) v_to_v,
  CAST(my_varchar AS NVARCHAR(100)) v_to_nv,
  CAST(my_nvarchar AS VARCHAR(100)) nv_to_v,
  CAST(my_nvarchar AS NVARCHAR(100)) nv_to_nv
FROM (
  SELECT
    CAST('мой VARCHAR' AS VARBINARY(50)) as my_varchar,
    CAST(N'мой NVARCHAR' AS VARBINARY(50)) as my_nvarchar 
) T
```

У меня под рукой студии нет, но по результату я думаю вы всё поймёте :)

С коллацией возможно ещё стоит поиграться, но это надо конкретный пример binary и результат запроса `SELECT @@VERSION`, точнее сказать трудно.